# Support Internships on Stack Overflow Jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I really like what SO is doing so far with Careers, but there is almost nothing for students. I know a lot of of students are looking for internships or just student jobs.

Since most students are already using SO everyday, being able to find a job at the same site would be a plus. This would also bring more students and employers to the website.

Servy is right, in the FAQ it doesn't specify employers can't post internships, but it also doesn't specify that employers should post them. I just thought a tag or an option button could make it clear for everyone.

For example:

> [image: example of internship selection]

Comment: I don't really have anything against this proposal, I just don't think it's very practicial. I doubt many employers are willing to pay to advertise student internships/jobs

Comment: I don't see anything in the careers FAQ indicating that jobs must be long term, rather than internships.  Did I just miss it?  I'm not seeing why someone can't already post an internship to careers?

Comment: @CarrieKendall I disagree, but more importantly, I'd say that [Joel would disagree](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/FindingGreatDevelopers.html).  He considers internships an essential part of finding great developers as an employer.  I can't imagine, given his feelings about their importance, that he'd scoff at the idea of a company willing to pay for good interns.

Comment: @Servy Whether Joel thinks it's a good idea or not doesn't mean that a majority of employers would be willing to pay for that. A pretty good indication of that would be that there is only one true internship listing, as far as I can tell. Either way, I'd be delighted to be wrong :)

Comment: @Servy I edited my question to answer your question

Comment: Internships are exclusively for students (although they're primarily for students).  Having an option for "internship" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Servy You are right this should replaced by Internship

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me at all if there were companies happy to pay to recruit internships. It's a major component of recruiting talent for lots of companies.

Comment: It certainly would make it a lot easier for me right now. I'm throwing bounties at this until they implement it (or I don't need an internship anymore)

Comment: I agree with @CarrieKendall. A typical internship is 3-6 months for a student. The average contract job (in software that I've seen) begins at 6 months. Employers pay monthly (or some time frame) to advertise the job opening. While this is a great idea, it may not be practical for the employer... Although if it is an unpaid internship, the employer would not be having to spend extra money for payroll.

Comment: The site for Careers support, according to [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support), is http://meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you for the feature request, @phil652!

Stack Overflow Jobs recently soft launched *internships* which allows a user to search and apply for internship jobs. It's also a great idea for students/fresh-grads/entry-level-developers/..etc to set up an alert for internship jobs so they would receive email alerts whenever new internships are available.

[image]